# I want to use copy function to deploy app services in multiple regions using ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-appservice

I'm trying to deploy some app services to multiple regions, the template worked fine when deployed to a single region, but when I add the copy function and use concat I get an error. what am i doing wrong?

```
"parameters": {
"regions": {
"type": "array",
"defaultValue": [
{
"location": "South America",
"prefix": "App-name"
},
{
"location": "North America",
"prefix": "App-Name"
}
],
"metadata": {
"description": "Locations"
}
}
},
"functions": [],
"variables": {},
"resources": [
{
"apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
"copy" : {
"name": "regionCopy",
"count": "[length(parameters('regions'))]"
},
"sku": {
"name": "F1"
},
"properties": {}
}
],

"outputs": {}
}
```

Comment: Are you using VS code or Visual studio or In Azure portal?

Comment: Use this code below the `copy`
```
"name": "[concat('-', parameters('regions')[copyIndex()].prefix, '')]",
"type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
"location": "[parameters('regions')[copyIndex()].location]",
```

Comment: Time to use bicep...

Answer (score 0):

- I have tried to deploy app service in different location using arm template
- Open azure poral and Search for **Custom deployment**

[image]

- Use the below code

```json
{
 "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
 "regions": {
  "type": "array",
 "defaultValue": [
{
"location": "WestUS2",
"prefix": "AppService1"
},
{
"location": "EastUS2",
"prefix": "AppService2"
}
],
"metadata": {
           "description": "Locations"
            }
        }
    },
"functions": [],
"variables": {},
"resources": [
{
        "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
"copy" : {
         "name": "regionCopy",
         "count": "[length(parameters('regions'))]"
         },
"name": "[concat('-', parameters('regions')[copyIndex()].prefix, '')]",
"type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
"location": "[parameters('regions')[copyIndex()].location]",
"sku": {
         "name": "F1"
       },
"properties": {}
    }
],

"outputs": { }
}
```

- After deploying Goto Azure portal and open your repository as below

[image]